# How to implement [x] -> x in scala using shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless

```scala
def unreturn(lx: Sized[List[Int], Nat._1]): Int = lx head
```

How to get the head of a list of one element using shapeless? This doesn't compile:

```
No implicit view available from List[Int] =>
scala.collection.GenTraversableLike[v.A,List[Int]].

not enough arguments for method sizedOps:
(implicit evidence$2: List[Int] =>
scala.collection.GenTraversableLike[v.A,List[Int]])shapeless.
SizedOps[v.A,List[Int],shapeless.Nat._1]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to include the type member in the type of your argument:

```
def unreturn(lx: Sized[List[Int], Nat._1] { type A = Int }): Int = lx.head
```

The problem is that *you* know that there's no (safe) way to build a `Sized[List[Int], _1]` with any other `A`, but the compiler still needs evidence.